# Cannot start the application. TypeError: Cannot read property 'definition' of undefined at getFieldsJsonSchemaFor

Tags: loopback

I'm getting an extremely weird error when trying to `npm start` my loopback application. I literally did nothing to the code and then this all of a sudden started to happen

> Cannot start the application. TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'definition' of undefined
>       at getFieldsJsonSchemaFor (/Users/vikramkhemlani/Desktop/loopback/node_modules/@loopback/repository-json-schema/dist/filter-json-schema.js:101:64)

I have the same exact code in another file (which i actually created a git repo from using this repo) but this one is throwing this error for some reason

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I went through the same issue.
Apparently there are caches which need to clean up before starting the application. (Expired caches also appear in openapi before I get into this issue)

The project needs to be clean and re-install packages by following:

```js
npm run clean
npm install
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.

However, I solved it when I tried the following.

- delete node_modules directory.
- npm install.

Answer (score 0):

*Hello from the LoopBack team*

This may be a bug in LoopBack introduced by recent changes. Please create a small application reproducing the problem (see our [Bug reporting instructions](https://loopback.io/doc/en/contrib/Reporting-issues.html#loopback-4x-bugs)) and open a new GitHub issue in https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/new